# Change shortcut properties by VBScript in InstallShield project

Tags: vbscript, runtime, installshield, shortcut

I have Express version of InstallShield and want to create simple project for my program.

I want to do "tricky" thing: for each feature in my IS project I want to create specific shortcut to my program (with a particular argument). For example:
- If user select "Feature 1" I want to create shortcut with argument "Feature 1";
- If select "Feature 2" - shortcut with argument "Feature 2" etc.

As I understand it is possible with VBScript: get feature name which currently selected and change property of shortcut. But I can't found how to get feature name (enumerate Session.FeatureRequestState ??) and how to set specified shortcut property (argument).
I hope somebody in this forum can help me.
I know I may create shortcut with pure VBScript using reateObject("Wscript.shell") etc. but it is more complicated way.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way for this, im my opinion, will be using several shortcuts with different components instead of CAs with VBS.:
 - create Components in each Feature you have;
 - create several shortcuts with different arguments;
 - attach Components to appropriate shortcuts.
Then when user chooses Feature1 installer installs only Component1 with appropriate shortcut with arguments.

Here is only question if installer allow to install both Features at the same time, then need to think up a bit another solution.

Comment: I tried this way and had not results.  I have Myprog.exe and want to create shortcut to this for Feature1 with argument "feature1" and etc.  I can copy Myprog.exe to the each feature But: when I created shortcut1 for feature1 (from Myprog.exe) and tried to create shortcut2 for feature2 (for Myprog2.exe) I get shortcut2 for feature1! I can't change feature for shortcut2. May be this is limitation or bug of Express version..

Comment: Checked by creating own installer with the same functional - and it works well. 1 common feature (may be hidden) with EXE file (+all other additional files), 2 shortcut features with 1 component in each. 2 Shortcuts with the same name, but with different Components (should be assigned to Shortcut features) and different Arguments.